# ExtJS underlilning validation

Tags: javascript, extjs

For validation, I use a parameter 
msgTarget: 'side'.
When you enter invalid data, underlining and an exclamation mark appear.

How to get rid of the underline?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve that is to override the base cls class of the element on its invalid behavior:

```
.x-form-invalid-field, textarea.x-form-invalid-field {
    background-image: none;
}​
```

The most recommended way is to create a custom CSS class to do that same stuff, and apply that to the element (component) as a property:

```
.x-form-invalid-field-without-underline {
    background-image: none;
}​

Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
    ... ,
    invalidCls: 'x-form-invalid-field-without-underline'
});
```